# Помощь с регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите регулярку составить

```
#1,0.71,1.42,45.0,1.2$
```

Это исходный текст 
то есть #параметр1,параметр2,параметр3,параметр4,параметр5$

Пытался так но без результатно `#(?<id>),*,*,*,*$`

Comment: А что получиться-то должно на выходе?

Comment: на выходе 5 параметров

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Printer;

my $text = '#1,0.71,1.42,45.0,1.2$';
my @data;
$text =~ /^#(.+)\$$/ and @data = split ',', $1;
p @data;
```

Вывод:

```
[
    [0] 1,
    [1] 0.71,
    [2] 1.42,
    [3] 45.0,
    [4] 1.2
]
```

Или на PHP:

```
$text = '#1,0.71,1.42,45.0,1.2$';
$data = explode( ',', trim( $text, '$#' ) );
print_r( $data );
```

Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 0.71
    [2] => 1.42
    [3] => 45.0
    [4] => 1.2
)
```